# Why does "grep" behave differently in this example?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I am trying to grep a line from a file that starts with 'Residue XXX'. It works when I have only 'Residue' but does not work if I have 'Residue XXX'  Any reasons for this behavior?

Here it is working:

```
grep  '^Residue' log.txt
Residue XXX highDenisity
```

and not working:

```
grep  '^Residue XXX' log.txt
```

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn -- obviously not: the first grep works.

Comment: Try: `grep '^Residue.XXX' log.txt`.  And look at what it returns with something like `od -c` or `cat -t`.

Comment: wow! it has tab in it

Comment: this what it exactly prints`0000000   R   e   s   i   d   u   e  \t   d   d   G  \t   R   o   t   a
0000020   m   e   r   P   r   o   b   a   b   i   l   i   t   y  \n` I changed the text in the question for simpler sake

Comment: but how would I now grep with tab in it

Comment: Use a `.` like I showed, or put a tab into the `grep` pattern string (control-V tab may be necessary). And note that our Shakespearian friend Malvolio hit the nail on the head and up-vote him and accept his answer.

Comment: perfect! `.` is magical

Comment: this does not work Residue\tddG but the . worked as you said Residue.ddG..

Comment: Using `\t` is a remarkably fraught process; it is mostly not translated, except when `bash` decides to do so.  I intended you to have an actual tab character in the regex, not a representation of a tab such as `\t` or `\011`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold up your hand if you think there's a tab character between `Residue` and `XXX`.

Comment: Plausible guess.  Are you going to help with how to diagnose that?  (`grep '^Residue' log.txt | od -c` springs to mind.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- I was digging through the `cat` documentation for something that would print out tabs.  Use a better regexp, I guess.

Comment: Oh, yes, '`cat` came back from Berkeley waving flags'...(SO or Google search should find that; see also http://quotes.cat-v.org/programming/).  `cat -v` would almost do the job ('v' for 'visible', but you need `-t` to see tabs too; it implies `-v`).

Comment: I found a better reference (in the BSD man page for `cat`, of course):  Rob Pike, _"UNIX Style, or cat -v Considered Harmful"_, USENIX Summer Conference Proceedings, 1983.

Answer (score 0):

Use a whitespace-agnostic regex instead.

```
grep '^Residue\s*XXX' log.txt
```

This regex covers multiple tabs or a tab and a space between the words.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just do a logical `and` with `awk` like this:

```
awk '/^Residue/ && /XXX/' file
```

This will only output lines that do start with `Residue` and also contain `XXX`

You can also make the `and` like this:

```
awk '/^Residue.*XXX/' file
```

Comment: Kinda killing a fly with a sledgehammer there, aren't you?  `grep  '^Residue' log.txt | grep XXX` would accomplish the same thing.

Comment: `awk` do this job without any hesitation.  This is one of the thing is designed to do. :)